# Swift SpriteKit initializer errors keeps coming out

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I wrote a Init inside my class, but errors keep appearing in the init, there are three errors: 
1. need a override keyword ; 
2. required initializer must be provided by subclass;
3. initializer may only declared within a type;

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
var man:SKSpriteNode
var runningManTextures = [SKTexture]()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
}


func loadMan() {
    loadManTextures()
    man.position.y -= man.size.height/2
    addChild(man)
}

func loadManTextures() {
    var runningAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "man")
    for i in 1...3 {
        var textureName = "man_\(i)"
        var temp = runningAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
        runningManTextures.append(temp)
    }
}

init(size:CGSize){

    super.init(size: size)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    }
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

Comment: I've shown you how to fix the errors, but really you should not waste Stack Overflow bandwidth on this sort of elementary stuff. Instead, learn Swift before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is illegal in Swift:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    init(size:CGSize){
        super.init(size: size)
    }
}
```

To make it legal, write it like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override init(size:CGSize){
        super.init(size: size)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Your *actual* code will then *still* be illegal because your `init(size:)` method does not initialize your `man` property, but fixing that is trivial and is a different issue in any case.